# Random Characters Appearing in Chrome Inspect Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to append a piece of HTML that has an onClick listener like this:

```
$("body").append('<i class="exit far fa-times-circle"  onClick = "deleteTrackingNumber("xqaK3NOiywXfKd2i3HG6Fm8HyMK2",'+ trackingNumberInstance +')"></i>');
```

I was looking for this to be my intended html:

```
<i class="exit far fa-times-circle" onclick="deleteTrackingNumber(" xqak3noiywxfkd2i3hg6fm8hymk2",1z619a2y9001268020)"></i>
```

To obtain the trackingNumberInstance variable, I find it on a Google Firebase Snapshot instance:

```
var trackingNumberInstance = childSnapshot.val().trackingNumber;
```

After appending the HTML, the onclick listener doesn't work as Chrome states:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

I looked to make sure Google Firebase is returning a correct value, and I get the following:
[image: Chrome Log]

Which is a perfectly fine value to read.

I then checked the Chrome HTML to see that jquery is not appending the correct value:

[image: Chrome HTML]

This doesn't look correct, as it has random " and = signs.

I tried regex to see if that would get rid of them with this expression:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g
```

Though this also didn't work.

Comment: You need to escape `"` inside `"`. Use  `\"`.

Comment: Your single quotes are also off. Please fix your quotation marks. Please show the intended HTML, without any Javascript.

Comment: Your intended HTML is invalid. Also, your second argument is undefined. What is `1z619a2y9001268020`? A string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can create elements like this:

```
var $i = $("<i>").addClass("exit far fa-times-circle");
$i.click(function (e) {
  deleteTrackingNumber("xqaK3NOiywXfKd2i3HG6Fm8HyMK2", trackingNumberInstance);
});
$("body").append($i);
```

Much more readable, and you don't have to carefully use/mask all those quotes.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You helped the guy *avoid* instead of **understand and solve** their problem.

Comment: Inline code is bad practice, doing it inside a string is worse. I agree that I helped avoid the problem, but don't agree that that's a bad thing. If you're trying to say I should improve my answer, why not say *that*?

Answer (score 0):

You double-quote the `onclick` attribute, yet you also use double-quotes inside of it.